# Running reduce() on jQuery collection

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6

I'm working on an application and I have a collection of DOM objects where I want to sum their combined widths. I wanted to use the `reduce()` function for this.

The variable containing the jQuery collection is called `menuItems` and my attempt looks like this:

```
menuItems.toArray().reduce((total, item) => total += item.clientWidth);
```

But weirdly, that function returns this output:

```
// "http://localhost:3000/97689982"
```

Which is equivalent to all of the widths concatenated together in a string *excluding* the first element.

Running something like `menuItems.toArray()[0].clientWidth` correctly outputs the width of the first item.

Comment: What is the input data inside `menuItems`? can you post it here too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You need to parse the client width from string to a number before `reducing` it.**

```
const totalClientWidth = menuItems.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + Number(cur.clientWidth), 0);
```